# Why does python's struct think little-endian and big-endian imply different lengths?

Tags: python, struct, byte, endianness

I thought that little-endian and big-endian numbers were the same size (in bytes). But python 2.7's struct module says this:

```
In [46]: struct.unpack('>L', datalen[4:8])[0]
Out[46]: 35098131

In [47]: struct.unpack('L', datalen[4:8])[0]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-f18e2a303d6c> in <module>()
----> 1 struct.unpack('L', datalen[4:8])[0]

error: unpack requires a string argument of length 8
```

Why is the big endian long 4 bytes but struct expects the little-endian long to be 8 bytes?

Comment: Try `struct.unpack('<L',...)`. And check the section on alignment and paddding in the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specifying `'L'` without `>` or `<` is not "little-endian"; it's native endianness **and** native size. The standard size is 4 bytes, but your machine's native size is 8.

If you explicitly want standard sized little-endian, use:

```
struct.unpack('<L', datalen[4:8])[0]
```

Comment: +1Wow, I wonder how many folks have been ( or someday will be..) stung by that. FWIW since you made me read the docs, `'=L'` is standard size / native endian.  Is "native size" intrinsic to  the machine architecture or determined by your c compiler?

Comment: @george: it depends on your machine architecture as the alignment is done to maximise memory throughput. See the `struct` module docs (quoted in my answer) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment).

Answer (score 3):

The default is `@` or *native* order, which is not necessarily little endian.

Native order uses native alignment:

> By default, C types are represented in the machine’s native format and byte order, and **properly aligned by skipping pad bytes** if necessary (according to the rules used by the C compiler).

(emphasis mine) and

> Native byte order is big-endian or little-endian, depending on the host system. For example, Intel x86 and AMD64 (x86-64) are little-endian; Motorola 68000 and PowerPC G5 are big-endian; ARM and Intel Itanium feature switchable endianness (bi-endian). Use `sys.byteorder` to check the endianness of your system.

It is the *alignment* that causes the size to differ, not the endianess.

The [C data structure alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Typical_alignment_of_C_structs_on_x86) is used to improve memory performance; you need to make sure you pick the right type for your data input. The C native alignment for a long is:

> A long long (eight bytes) will be 8-byte aligned.

To compare between little and big endianess without native alignment, use `<` and `>` when comparing:

```
struct.unpack('<L', datalen[4:8])[0]
```